# Nneed to download IoT Core Dashboard v1.0.1708.31003

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

From where can I download IoT Core Dashboard v1.0.1708.31003? I need this specific version to flash my image on the USB. 
I am able to download the latest version but this with version the flashed image on the USB does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not provide the download link for old version. When you flashed image on USB, is there any error info displayed? Please provide more detail info about that.You can send feedback to help microsoft to improve the experience on the latest version.
[image]

Comment: In the latest dashboard Braswell(Intel Atom x5-E8000) is not listed. So i select Intel[MinnowBoard Turbot/MAX (64)] from the Device Type options and OS Build as Custom. Th USB seems to be flashed with the image but the processor does not boot with it after connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use following command to flash ffu image on Intel Atom processor x5-E8000:

```
dism.exe /apply-image /ImageFile:Flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /skipplatformcheck
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When applying the image through DISM tool, i am getting the error - "Attempting to flash a non anti-theft image or an unsupported anti-theft image on an anti-theft device.". Do you have any information on it?

Comment: Could you please provide the error log when running the dism tool?